# analyze of two queries performance

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

In a class about "Effect of indexing on performance" the lecturer used this example to show us how a prepare index can increase the performance
first query:

```
SELECT
    SOH.CustomerID,
    SOH.SalesOrderID,
    SOH.OrderDate,
    C.TerritoryID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SOH.CustomerID
                        ORDER BY SOH.OrderDate ) AS Row_Num
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
JOIN Sales.Customer AS C
    ON SOH.CustomerID = C.CustomerID;
GO
```

second query:

```
WITH Sales
AS
(
    SELECT
        CustomerID,
        OrderDate,
        SalesOrderID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerID
                            ORDER BY OrderDate ) AS Row_Num
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
)
SELECT
    Sales.CustomerID,
    Sales.SalesOrderID,
    Sales.OrderDate,
    C.TerritoryID,
    Sales.Row_Num
FROM Sales
JOIN Sales.Customer AS C
    ON C.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID;
GO
```

both queries return same output but second one has very lower cost:
[image: compare of actual plan]
unfortunately I couldn't understand the reason of this difference in cost

Comment: Your question is unclear. None of the code you presented has anything to do with indexes. Also while the `Query cost (relative to the batch)` *might* give you an idea of which query will be more performant, all `Cost` metrics in execution plans are estimates and generally are only worth a grain of salt. And you're only looking at the **estimated** execution plan which itself can be wildly different than the **actual** execution plan. You'd have to actually run the queries with the actual execution plan turned on to get the real picture. Also, `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;` is your friend here.

Comment: When asking performance questions, upload the actual execution plan XML to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question. FWIW, I get a different plans using a fresh AdventureWorks2019 OLTP database backup. Have you made any data/index changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are cost estimates, not literal measurements of cost.  The 4% difference between them could likely be explained by the use of the Sort operation in the first plan, which the other didn't use.

However, the real proof of performance isn't looking at plans. It's measuring the performance. I ran these queries 50 times and averaged the execution. The first query, not using the CTE, ran in 113ms on average with 726 reads. The second query, using the CTE, ran in 134ms on average with 812 reads. So, the costs are almost literally reversed from the estimates when it comes to actual runtime metrics.

Specifically, why are there two plans for what is logically the same query? I'm not sure. I'd have to spend a lot more time digging in. Logically, both are doing the same work, but the second plan deals with the ROW_NUMBER prior to the JOIN, likely because of defining it as a CTE.

Comment: I don't have a copy of AW handy to test on, but what is the memory grant difference between the two? The top query has to sort data for the windowing function, and the bottom query doesn't.

Comment: Good spot. Should have checked. 7762 for the first query, 2752 for the second.